# How to show real time input using javascript in input tag?

Tags: javascript, input

How can I make this script run by replacing textarea tag with input tag? I used input tag in my page and wanna add this code but this code used textarea. if I change textarea to input the code doesn't work.

```js
function setFontText(text) {
  document.getElementById("Courier_new").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("Arial_Black").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textField0" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:'Alex Brush';" onkeyup="javascript:setFontText(this.value);" rows="2" name="textField0"></textarea> Multiple text area:

<textarea id="Courier_new" class="fontTextArea2" style="font-family:Courier;" autocomplete="off" name="Courier new"></textarea>

<textarea id="Arial_Black" class="fontTextArea2" style="font-family:Arial; " autocomplete="off" name="Arial Black"></textarea>
```

Comment: For `input`s and `textarea`s, assign to their `value`, not their `innerHTML` if you want to change their *value*.

Comment: Could you provide what you have tried, what happened then, and want you would expect to happen instead.

Comment: it works with getElementById, but if i wanna make it work with getElementsByClassName, how can i achieve that? if i replace the getElementById function with getElementsByClassName, code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this:-

```
function setFontText(text) {
  document.getElementById("Courier_new").value = text;
  document.getElementById("Arial_Black").value = text;
}
```

Or,
Using  document.getElementsByClassName

The method .getElementsByClassName() returns an array-like object of elements.so you have to access first element (if there is any).

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("anyclass);
var value = elements[0].value;

alert(value); // 1
```

or,
you could also use the .querySelector() method:

```
var value = document.querySelector('.anyclass').value;
alert(value); // 1
```

Comment: it works with getElementById, but if i wanna make it work with getElementsByClassName, how can i achieve that?
if i replace the getElementById function with getElementsByClassName, code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Register the function:

```
function setFontText(text) {
  document.getElementById("Courier_new").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("Arial_Black").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Call the function with a string as parameter.

```
setFontText("TEXT");
```

it works fine with textarea as well. Syntax would be like this.
Here for the input field in stackoverflow:

var x = document.getElementById("wmd-input")
x.innerText = "TEXTFIELDINPUT"

or

x.innerHTML = "TEXTFIELDINPUT"*

Comment: ahh you updated the question you want to set a different font?

Comment: updated my answer, you need to give a string as a input for the funciton.

Comment: and your example code snippet, works fine. so I don't get what you want to achieve.